# Node.js and Apache for single domain same server

Tags: node.js, apache, angular

I built a RESTful website, and it is written in Angular2(front end) and Php(backend). Since I am using Angular Universal, I need Node.js to pre-process the Angular scripts. How can I configure my server to host both Node.js and Apache? I searched online, but can't find any resources related to "sharing Node.js and Apache on **SINGLE** domain"...

How to configure my Apache to route "everthing" to the /dist/ folder (and served by Node.js) except for the URI that are prefix with /api/ and /uploads/ (route to the /php/ folder).

**[Back-end] Api Php script:**

If `www.example.com/api/?...?`, then use this script `/var/www/example.com/public_html/php/api.php` to process it.

**Uploaded images:**

If asking for uploaded img files (`www.example.com/uploads/[img*.png]`), then try to look inside this `/var/www/example.com/public_html/php/uploads/[img*.png]` folder.

**[Front-end] Html, Js, etc...:**

Everyting `www.example.com` (except the /api/ and /uploads/), then ask Node.js to run it from this `/var/www/example.com/public_html/dist/` folder.

I guess it is related to **proxy** and **proxy_http**, but I don't know how to configure it since I can't find any resources related to sharing both systems for `single domain`...

Answer (score 0):

i think you should Run Node.js on a different port (e.g 8080) and use Reverse proxy in Apache config (virtual hosts) like this:

```
ProxyPass        /api http://www.example.com/php/
ProxyPassReverse /api http://www.example.com/php/
ProxyPass        /uploads http://www.example.com/php/uploads/
ProxyPassReverse /uploads http://www.example.com/php/uploads/
ProxyPass        / http://www.example.com:8080/dist/
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.example.com:8080/dist/
```

and then use htaccess rewrite rules for your uploads and api

you can read more about [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)